# Navigate to MediatR handler in Visual Studio 2019 (or perhaps Rider)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, rider, mediatr

Im currently in a project that uses mediatR quite alot. I have a problem following the code. Currently I Search for "IRequestHandler<RequestObject", which feels a bit medieval

Is there any way to for example navigate to (or peek) the handler(s) of a mediator.Send(request) in Visual Studio 2019?

(any way in Jetbrains Rider?)

Answer (score 3):

Both ReSharper and Rider can help you here.

Place the cursor on the `RequestObject` and then call:

- In Rider: `Navigate | Navigate To | Consuming APIs` action
- In Visual Studio: `ReSharper | Navigate | Navigate To | Consuming APIs` action

Visit [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigate_To_Consuming_APIs.html) to learn more about the Consuming APIs feature.

Comment: I think Resharper bogs down VS too much to be usable, but super, thanks for the Rider-tip